# VBA - autofilter - always hide exact value

Tags: vba, excel, filtering

I have code for autofilter, which always choose "TOP" and "TOP 100" in column R:

```
Sub Filter()

With Worksheets("Overview")
Range("A1:S1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S$9999").AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="=TOP", _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=TOP 100"
End With
End Sub
```

But I would need to add another filter, which will always hide zeros in column P. I mean, that I know, that I have to put values into "Criteria", which I would like to filtered. But those values will be variables, but there always will be 0, which I would need to hide. Does anyone know, how to do that, please?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub Filtre()
    Dim r As Range

    Set r = Worksheets("Overview").Range("A:S")

    r.AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="=TOP", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=TOP 100"
    r.AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:="<>0", Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try `Criteria1:="<>0"` for filtering all except 0

Comment: Sorry, I have explaint it incorrectly. I would like to filter all values except 0.

Comment: OK I have changed my answer...now its OK.

Answer (score 1):

This code will also filter out 0 from column P:

```
Sub Filter()

    With Worksheets("Overview").Range("$A$1:$S$9999")
        .AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="=TOP", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=TOP 100"
        .AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:="<>0"
    End With

End Sub
```